# PHP Regex expression to validate a name input

Tags: php, regex, validation

As part of my validation I have the following regex expression:

```
    ^
# Prevent 3+ consecutive letters: 'wheee'
(?!\w*([a-zA-Z])\g{-1}{2,})

[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z]|'(?!')){0,}

# Words or '&' are space or hyphen separated
(?:
  [ -]

  # Prevent 3+ consecutive letters: 'wheee' (for rest of words)
  (?!\w*([a-zA-Z])\g{-1}{2,})
  (?:[a-zA-Z]|'(?!')){1,}
|
  [ -]
  &
)*$
```

I was wondering the effectiveness of the expression and/or possible pitfalls?

Comment: I'm missing a short explanation why you need this expression and what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

One possible pitfall is that several celebrities cannot pass your "validation" code. Do you really want [Renée Zellweger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9e_Zellweger) and [Goran Ivanišević](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goran_Ivani%C5%A1evi%C4%87) being mad at you?

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

You use both lowercase and uppercase everywhere. This can possibly be symplified with (inline) modifiers:

```
(?i)[a-z]
```

Personally I use quantifiers as a "sugar" instead of explicit interval specifying:

```
{0,} ==> *
{1,} ==> +
```

Comment: would there be any speed or other benefit to using quantifiers as a "sugar" instead of explicit interval specifying?